# How to fetch Resting energy value from HealthKit which has same value as Health App's value?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm using apple's [HealthKit sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Fit/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014583-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) however **resting energy** value shown in **Health app** in iPhone doesn't match with the value fetched in sample app.

As per apple docs, **HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBasalEnergyBurned** is representing **resting energy** so I fetched this value from the HealthKit but the value I received doesn't match with the **resting energy** shown in **Health App**.

So I came across the apple's [HealthKit sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Fit/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014583-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) where they are calculating resting energy based on formula:

```
// Calculates the user's total basal (resting) energy burn based off of their height, weight, age,
    // and biological sex. If there is not enough information, return an error.
    private func fetchTotalBasalBurn(completion: @escaping (HKQuantity?, Error?) -> Void)
    {
        let todayPredicate: NSPredicate = self.predicateForSamplesToday()

        let weightType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass)!
        let heightType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.height)!

        let queryWeigth: HKCompletionHandle = {
            (weight, error) -> Void in

            guard let weight = weight else {
                completion(nil, error)

                return
            }

            let queryHeigth: HKCompletionHandle = {
                (height, error) -> Void in

                if height == nil {
                    completion(nil, error)

                    return;
                }

                var dateOfBirth: Date!

                do {

                    dateOfBirth = try self.healthStore!.dateOfBirth()

                } catch {

                    completion(nil, error)

                    return
                }

                var biologicalSexObjet: HKBiologicalSexObject!

                do {

                    biologicalSexObjet = try self.healthStore!.biologicalSex()

                } catch {

                    completion(nil, error)

                    return
                }

                // Once we have pulled all of the information without errors, calculate the user's total basal energy burn
                let basalEnergyButn: HKQuantity? = self.calculateBasalBurnTodayFromWeight(weight, height: height, dateOfBirth: dateOfBirth!, biologicalSex: biologicalSexObjet)

                completion(basalEnergyButn, nil)
            }

            if let healthStore = self.healthStore {

                healthStore.mostRecentQuantitySample(ofType: heightType, predicate: todayPredicate, completion: queryHeigth)
            }
        }

        if let healthStore = self.healthStore {
            healthStore.mostRecentQuantitySample(ofType: weightType, predicate: nil, completion: queryWeigth)
        }
    }

    private func calculateBasalBurnTodayFromWeight(_ weight: HKQuantity?, height: HKQuantity?, dateOfBirth: Date, biologicalSex: HKBiologicalSexObject) -> HKQuantity?
    {
        // Only calculate Basal Metabolic Rate (BMR) if we have enough information about the user
        guard let weight = weight, let height = height else {

            return nil
        }

        // Note the difference between calling +unitFromString: vs creating a unit from a string with
        // a given prefix. Both of these are equally valid, however one may be more convenient for a given
        // use case.
        let heightInCentimeters: Double = height.doubleValue(for: HKUnit(from:"cm"))
        let weightInKilograms: Double = weight.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.gramUnit(with: HKMetricPrefix.kilo))

        let nowDate = Date()
        let ageComponents: DateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.year], from: dateOfBirth, to: nowDate)
        let ageInYears: Int = ageComponents.year!

        // BMR is calculated in kilocalories per day.
        let BMR: Double = self.calculateBMRFromWeight(weightInKilograms: weightInKilograms, height: heightInCentimeters, age: ageInYears, biologicalSex: biologicalSex.biologicalSex)

        // Figure out how much of today has completed so we know how many kilocalories the user has burned.
        let (startOfToday, endOfToday): (Date, Date) = self.datesFromToday()

        let secondsInDay: TimeInterval = endOfToday.timeIntervalSince(startOfToday)
        let percentOfDayComplete: Double = nowDate.timeIntervalSince(startOfToday) / secondsInDay

        let kilocaloriesBurned: Double = BMR * percentOfDayComplete

        let basalBurn = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.kilocalorie(), doubleValue: kilocaloriesBurned)

        return basalBurn
    }

/// Returns BMR value in kilocalories per day. Note that there are different ways of calculating the
    /// BMR. In this example we chose an arbitrary function to calculate BMR based on weight, height, age,
    /// and biological sex.
    private func calculateBMRFromWeight(weightInKilograms: Double, height heightInCentimeters: Double, age ageInYears: Int, biologicalSex: HKBiologicalSex) -> Double
    {
        var BMR: Double = 0

        if biologicalSex == .male {
            BMR = 66.0 + (13.8 * weightInKilograms) + (5.0 * heightInCentimeters) - (6.8 * Double(ageInYears))

            return BMR
        }

        BMR = 655 + (9.6 * weightInKilograms) + (1.8 * heightInCentimeters) - (4.7 * Double(ageInYears))

        return BMR
    }
```

I'm tried the sample app to fetch **resting energy** however still resting energy value shown in health app and sample app doesn't have same value.

Could any body tell me how to fetch resting energy or what is the calculation used by **Health App** to find **resting energy**?

It would be great if someone can give me some pointers on it, I'm pretty new to HealthKit.

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Ashok I've included a working answer. Apple's sample code is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Apple's sample is outdated. As of iOS 8 and watchOS 2 there's a call to retrieve this information in the same way that active calories are retrieved; simply change the identifier. [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquantitytypeidentifier/1615512-basalenergyburned)

```
HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.basalEnergyBurned)
```

Don't forget to include the additional permission to read this data as well.

Comment: I am trying with the new identifier(basalEnergyBurned) only. But, still the data mismatches with the one shown in health app

Comment: it's 2023 and I still am seeing the mismatch